# NMinimize or other means for mixed-integer problem with constrains

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Given two real numbers `0 < x < 1/2`, `0 < y < 1/2` and an integer `n`, harmonics are defined as `h = Abs[Mod[nx x + ny y, 1, -1/2]]` where `nx = [0,1,2,...,n]`, `ny = [-n,-n+1,...,n-1,n]` if `nx != 0` and `ny = [1,2,...,n]` if `nx == 0`. The problem is to find `x` and `y` given several harmonics `hs`.

If `x` and `y` are in `hs`, it is possible to brute force the solution. The problems is when values are not in `hs`. I was hoping to use `NMinimize` for this problem, but it doesn't seem to work. Perhabs, I'm missing something with `NMinimize` or an alternative method?

```
x = 0.12345 ;
y = 0.31345 ;

n = 5 ;
r = Range[-n, n] ;
ps = DeleteCases[Tuples[r, 2], Alternatives[{x_, _} /; x <0 , {0,0}, {0, x_} /; x < 0]] ;
ps = DeleteCases[ps, Alternatives[{1, 0}, {0, 1}]] ;

ClearAll[harmonics] ;
harmonics[basis_][pair_] := Abs[Mod[Total[pair*basis], 1.0, -0.5]] ;
hs = Map[harmonics[{x,y}], ps] ;

ps // Short
hs // Short
(* {{0,2},{0,3},{0,4},{0,5},{1,-5},{1,-4},<<47>>,{5,1},{5,2},{5,3},{5,4},{5,5}}  *)
(* {0.3731,0.05965,<<54>>,0.12895,0.1845} *)
```

Objective to minimize:

```
ClearAll[objective] ;
objective[data_][nxs_, nys_, x_, y_] := Norm[Abs[Mod[nxs*x + nys*y, 1, -1/2]] - data] ;
```

Use a sampe from all avalible data:

```
size = 10 ;
SeedRandom[1] ;
data = RandomSample[hs, size] ;
nxs = Table[Indexed[nx,i] , {i, 1, size}] ;
nys = Table[Indexed[ny,i] , {i, 1, size}] ;
objective[data][Apply[Sequence, Transpose[Map[AssociationThread[hs -> ps], data]]], x, y]
(* 0. *)
```

Minimize:

```
NMinimize[
  { 
    objective[data][nxs, nys, hx, hy],
    0.0 < hx < 0.5, 
    0.0 < hy < 0.5,
    Element[nxs, NonNegativeIntegers] , 
    Element[nys, Integers] ,
    Abs[nxs]  <= n,
    Abs[nys]  <= n
  },
  Join[{hx, hy}, nxs, nys] ,
  Method->{"DifferentialEvolution", "ScalingFactor" -> 0.25, "SearchPoints" -> 3*size} 
]
(* {0.158976,{hx->0,hy->0.28688,Subscript[nx, 1]->1,Subscript[nx, 2]->1,Subscript[nx, 3]->0,Subscript[nx, 4]->1,Subscript[nx, 5]->1,Subscript[nx, 6]->1,Subscript[nx, 7]->0,Subscript[nx, 8]->0,Subscript[nx, 9]->0,Subscript[nx, 10]->1,Subscript[ny, 1]->-2,Subscript[ny, 2]->2,Subscript[ny, 3]->0,Subscript[ny, 4]->-1,Subscript[ny, 5]->1,Subscript[ny, 6]->-1,Subscript[ny, 7]->2,Subscript[ny, 8]->1,Subscript[ny, 9]->1,Subscript[ny, 10]->-1}}  *)
```

Comment: Results might have been different due to unfied seed, now fixed